# One time msgBox on Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, msgbox

I need to put an alert on my teams planner on Google Sheets to remind people to do something.

Someone told me is unusable to see this popup any time the file opened.

How can I fix my code for **showing popup once a day for each people?**

A user suggested me to save user email in a range: how to check **if the email of my specialists are in the range?**

**How can I delete the range values every day?**

```
function meet() 
{
  //get active user email
  var currentEmail =     Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log('currentEmail = ' + currentEmail);

  //read values into range
  var data =     SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("email!A1").getValues();
  Logger.log('data = ' + data);

  if (data == "") {
    //show the dialog box for the meet
    var response = Browser.msgBox('Ciao!', 'Hai inserito le tue riunioni/meet di oggi?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    Logger.log(response);
    if (response == "yes") {
      Browser.msgBox('Ottimo!', 'Buon lavoro!', Browser.Buttons.OK);
      Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
      } else {
      Browser.msgBox('mmmh!', 'Ricordati di farlo!', Browser.Buttons.OK);
      Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
    }

    //create a named range
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var range = ss.getRange("email!A1");

    //write user email into range
    range.setValue(currentEmail);
    ss.setNamedRange("email", range);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can perhaps collect the email of a user when the message has shown. And do not send message box if the User has one of the flagged email. And refresh the email liste daily

Comment: Hi Benoit! Is a solution, thanks! Do you have an example of code I could use? I also thinked to use a variable when the buttons are clicked but I don't know how to set it for the single people :/

Comment: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()

Use this after your if else, then insert the email in a named_range. Maybe in a hidden sheet that you name "Parameters"

And at the beggining of your script you look in that the email of the current user is not in your list. 
Make sure to refresh the named_range envery day. 

You can insert your meet function in the onOpen()

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user

AppScript documentation is well written

Comment: Hi @BenoitDrogou! Thanks for your info. I reach to stop the dialog box when **my email** is in a range. I don't understand how to check if **any mail** is in the range :/

Comment: @BenoitDrogou Then I haven't found how to delete the range values every day. Have you got a reference? Thanks a lot